# How to add an upload prescription file in woocommerce checkout?

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I need to add an upload file filed in woocommerce checkout. I tried this way.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'prescription_upload_field1');

function prescription_upload_field1($checkout)
{
    echo '<div id="prescription_upload_field"><h3>' . __('Prescription Upload') . '</h3>';

    echo '<div class="prescription-file-upload-field">';
    woocommerce_form_field('prescription_file_upload', array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __('Upload Prescription'),
        'required' => false,
    ), $checkout->get_value('prescription_file_upload'));
    echo '</div>';

    echo '</div>';
}
```

This will not show me the file upload button.

**woocommerce_form_field** function not show the file uplaod, if i add a text field it will show .

Can some one help me to achieve this task.

Comment: The type `file` is not available in woocommerce.

Comment: woocommerce_form_field its not supporting it due to security reasons. Add url field and customer can upload the file on any free to share platform - google drive etc. and provide link to access it.

Comment: You can use the `woocommerce_form_field` filter hook to add your `file` type.